# simulating mininet without controller

Tags: http, mininet, sdn, topology, switching

I have a 2x2 leaf spine topology as seen inthe picture[2x2 leaf spine topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu3JB.png), I want to test it with out SDN controller, the prolbem is that connection between hosts of different switches doesn't work, even the ping :-(. Please there is any way can I solve this? Because I have to make comparaison beteween the experiments (with and without controller).

And there is any way to get metrics or any scenario please for http traffic?

Thank you :-).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. In the scenario where you must not use a controller, you are going to have to turn a normal node into a router. Take a look at this: [(mininet) How to create a topology with two routers and their respective hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46595423/mininet-how-to-create-a-topology-with-two-routers-and-their-respective-hosts)